# how to read values from command line and use them in bootstrapped annotation config class to define spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, command-line, configuration

i have my main class as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource cmdLineSrc = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);     
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(cmdLineSrc);
    ctx.register(MyConfig.class);

    ctx.refresh();
    ctx.start();

    MyClass myclass = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class);
    // do something...
}
```

now in my MyApp.config, i have following..

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

however, when i try to get values out, i get NPE.

```
env.getProperty("something");
```

what am i missing here? I do have @PropertySource as below (which works fine), but could that cause any issues here?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:my.properties" })
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
```

Comment: I don't understand: you want to access some command line properties in your Spring configuration? And what do you want to do with those command line properties? Show the code you use to do something with those properties!

Answer (score 1):

@PropertySource declaration was overriding environment variables in my @Configuration class.  i removed it and i was able to retrieve values i entered in command line.